# How to get email id in example@abc.com instead of "CN= example/OU= Server/O=company" in lotus notes in java

Tags: java, lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

Hi i when i get the username from domino designer in the below mentioned way

```
    Session session = getSession();
    AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
    String userName=session.getUsername(); 
    system.out.println("UserName="+uesrName);
```

i am getting the username in the format "CN= example/OU= Server/O=company" but i want to be in the usual format like example@abc.com .Can anyone please tell how to get it in Java.Is there any other approach to get the username in the expected format.please help.It would be great if some references are provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

example@abc.com is NOT a username but an email- address (that can be used in the username field to login for Webservices / traveler / ldap / etc. if the server is configured accordingly).

There are different ways to get an email- address for a given username, the easiest might be the usage of the Directory- Class and its method "lookupNames".

Here is an example taken from the Designer Help:

```
  Session session = getSession();
  AgentContext agentContext = session.getAgentContext();
  Directory dir = session.getDirectory("NameOfYourServer");
  String userName=session.getUsername(); 
  DirEntryCollection direc = dir.lookupNames("($Users)",userName,"email");
  DirEntry dirent = direc.getFirstEntry()
  while (dirent != null) {
    String name = dirent.getItemValue("InternetAddress");
    System.out.println(InternetAddress);
    dirent = direc.getNextEntry(); }
```

Designer help can be found in many places (locally installed if Designer is installed) or e.g. [here](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/domhelp/v8r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/H_GETDIRECTORY_METHOD.html)

Comment: :i tried the way u told.$Users view seems to be referring to the Mail Contacts.So when i printed the values of the InternetAddress i got the value what i have saved while creating the contact.But i need  the mapped email Id for a particular username.Can u plz tell how to get the email ID for a corresponding UserName.

Comment: Pass the name of your Domino server into the getDirectory method instead of null.

Comment: If the code runs on a local workstation, then the directory you get is your personal names.nsf. Only if the code runs on a server, then you get a server directory. The ($Users) contains usernames / mailaddresses in all variations... I edited the code to use the server addressbook.. Thanx Richard